# Как проверить, что приложение возвращает корректно Exit Status Code?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть приложение, которое построено как windows приложение (не консольное!). Через консоль программе передаю параметры. Программа отрабатывает и я устанавливаю `Environment.ExitCode` в нужное значение 0 или 1. Дальше я в той же консли запускаю  `echo %ERRORLEVEL%`, чтобы проверить статус выполненного кода. Всегда возвращается ноль, чтобы я не устанавливал в `Environment.ExitCode`. Если построить приложение как Консольное, то отрабатывает нормально и если код выполнился корректно, то возвращается ноль, если нет, то -1. Приложение долно быть построено как windows приложение, поэтому у меня вопрос - Как проверить, что приложение возвращает корректно Exit Status Code? Почему всегда возвращается 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно запускать *.exe и ожидать его завершения в консоли (по дефолту, после запуска windows приложение, управление сразу возвращается в консоль, поэтому мы и не видим изменений в error level). Нужно запускать так:

```
start /wait <exe file>
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

echo `%ERRORLEVEL%` возвращает статус

Comment: Спасибо, есть еще один вариант. Для проверки можно создать отдельное тест-приложение